# Unable to mount external USB HDD because of GPT on debian

Tags: debian, usb-drive, gpt

I have tried to mount an external USB 3.0 hdd on my debian virtual machine (I'm using VirtualBox). I have tried to mount it using `mount /dev/sdb1/ /media/vol1/` but I get the following error:

```
mount: can't find /dev/sdb1 in /etc/fstab of /etc/mtab
```

I have tried to use `fdisk -l`, the error I get is the following:

```
    WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000170586112 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121597 cylinders, total 1953458176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  1953458175   976729087+  ee  GPT
```

This is the result of `parted -l`:

```
Model: WD My Passport 0748 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                   Flags
 1      20,5kB  210MB   210MB   fat32        EFI System Partition   boot
 2      210MB   1000GB  1000GB  hfsx         Apple_HFSX_Untitled_2
```

How can I mount the hdd and read its content?

Comment: Please include the command you ran which gives the error. The output you show and the error you quote are from `fdisk` which has nothing to do with mounting.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I improved my question, I hope that now it il clearer.

Comment: Please follow the suggestion in your error message. [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo parted -l`. Don't take a screenshot, just copy paste it into your question using the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) available. Also, check `man mount`. The format of the mount command is `mount partition mount_point`, so you would need something like `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/disk`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I did use mount correctly, it was a typo in the question. I also put the results of the commands formatted correctly instead of the previous picture.

Comment: I think I fixed the problem. If I connect the external HDD to a USB 2.0 port I can mount it very simply. Should I post this as an answer?

Comment: Are you sure you want to mount the EFI partition of your HDD? That is what is on `/dev/sdb1`. Also, just fyi, AFAIK Linux doesn't have filesystem drivers that support writing to `hfsx` filesystems, which is what you have on `/dev/sdb2`.

Comment: I have been able to mount the `hfsx` partition but read-only. It is enough for me, since I only wanted to recover some files.

Comment: I think the reason for the error message is quite simple: you need to drop the trailing slash from `/dev/sdb1/` and just use `/dev/sdb1`. With the trailing slash `mount` will treat `/dev/sdb1` as a directory and search for a device to mount there in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @giovi321 is there any solution for usb3?